# Custom property injection in Castle Windsor for Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, castle-windsor

I have a Windows Forms application which makes use of an MVP pattern. Each view is a WinForms user control and is backed by a presenter which handles non-UI concerns. The application makes use of Castle Windsor, and all views presenters and many other components are resolved via the Windsor Container.

What I would like to be able to do is customise property injection for the user control views. My views don't make a whole lot of use of property injection, but it is occasionally very useful and works well. The problem is, my user controls often contain nested controls, which in turn can contain other nested controls, and property injection is not going to work for these nested controls, because they were not directly resolved via the container.

What I would like to do is to configure property injection for components that inherit from the SWF `Control` class. In addition to finding properties on the component, I would like to also find properties on nested controls (in the `Controls`) collection and inject into these nested properties as well.

I know that Castle Windsor is extremely flexible and configurable so this may be possible. I need a bit of a nudge in the right direction though. Is this possible? Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Comment: It's so quiet I can hear the crickets. This must either be something nobody else wants to do, something nobody should ever try to do, or something that is not possible.

Comment: if you want Windsor to manage dependencies of your nested controls why not let Windsor manage them, including creating them?

Comment: I am talking about nested controls that are created as part of the InitializeComponent method, where all controls that are created by the designer are constructed. I still want to be able to use the WinForms designer to build my user controls. It is these controls that I would like to be able to inject dependencies into. In effect, treating theses properties as if they belonged to the outer user control.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly I think that the only way to achieve what you want is by some sort of poor man's dependency injection because the way the winforms designer generates a method that constructs the various sub-controls you speak of makes it decidedly uncondusive to IoC.

I am not sure you will be able to do property injection but you can utilise the constructor, here is a hair-brained scheme I have just concocted ...

Firstly, create some way to access your windsor container - something like this would probably do the trick:

```
public static class MyContainer
{
    private static readonly IWindsorContainer _container = Bootstrap();
           
    // I did it like this so that there is no explicit dependency
    // on Windsor - this would be the only place you need to change
    // if you want an alternate container (how much you care about
    // that is up to you)
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    private static IWindsorContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

        // ... whatever else you need to do here

        return container;
    }
}
```

Secondly, in the inner controls, where you want some properties injected do something like this (I went for the good ol' ILogger as an example of something you may want injected):

```
public partial class MyFancyControl : UserControl
{    
    // Constructor to keep the winforms designer happy
    public MyFancyControl() 
        : this (MyContainer.Resolve<ILogger>())
    {
        // Intentionally always blank as this 
        // is an un-unit-testable method
    }
    
    // Constructor that does the actual work
    public MyFancyControl(ILogger logger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Logger = logger;
    }
    
    public ILogger Logger { get; private set; }
}
```

*Note: using the logger raises one of the couple of obvious smells in this - sometimes you don't register such a component with the container at all (usually you have a null logger) so you may need to hook up some sort of mechanism for that but I leave that up to you if you need it or not.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's using the dreaded service locator pattern, but it will work. One important consideration here is that you would have to explicity release any component you resolved this way, because otherwise you will get memory-leaks, at least for non-singleton components. The place to release it would be in the Dispose() method. It gets more complicated having to remember whether the component was resolved via the container or not. Yes it will work, but I am wondering if there is a better way using the "innards" of Castle Windsor to keep track.

Comment: I just had a thought: You could use the typed factory facility: pass  a factory in the way described above then use the factory to get whatever you need that way Windsor will control the release policies of the things that are resolved from the factory:  http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx - you might have to bend your architecture a bit to make a factory seem sensible for this to look reasonable though - there are a bunch of ways to release the components created by the factory - may not be any better than releasing in the dispose the frm

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll see if it works for me, and I'll let you know.